# Season 3 - how is Aktion getting inside the dome?

Tags: under-the-dome

I missed the second half of the season three premiere, somehow Aktion has managed to send in a scientist, hired goons and explosives. How do they get into the dome from the outside world?

Answer (score 2):

They followed Barbie's dad.

Remember in Season 2, we learned that there's an entrance into the Dome

> in Barbie's old family home, through the fallout shelter door

that brings you up in the lake near Bird Island.

By the end of Season 2, the egg had made its way outside the dome, into Aktion's possession.  When Melanie wanted to get it back, she told Barbie's dad how to get into the dome. In the S3 premiere, we see other people from Aktion follow him and find the entrance.