# Why don't the occupants of Chester's Mill leave the dome?

Tags: under-the-dome

As a follow up to this question:

> [Season 3 - how is Aktion getting inside the dome?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97639/season-3-how-is-aktion-getting-inside)

Maybe I missed the reason in a previous episode, but why don't the characters leave the dome the same way they got in?

Comment: Well this has clearly become 100% unrecognizable from the book. Interesting.

Comment: Through water you mean :O try and die.